# Chirality in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, chirality

In quantum mechanics, chirality is preserved for massless particles.

But in Standard Model, is there any reason for chirality to be preserved for **massless particles** in annihilation diagrams? (unless it would not be allowed like right-handed neutrinos)

For example, if I have a left-handed neutrino and antineutrino colliding, propagating as z-boson...

Is there any reason for the outgoing massless particles to be only left? Or can they be right also? Outgoing particles could be **massless** electron and positron.

I don't think Z-boson conserves any chirality, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You may have garbled your question. The *Z* may flip chirality for charged leptons, but not for neutrinos (since these are chargeless), so a left neutrino needs to merge with a right antineutrino to form a *Z*. Run to your PDG booklet review! Then write the relevant couplings in your question. Words are more ambiguous than formulas.

Answer (score 1):

First, neutrinos are now known to have mass, meaning "sterile" right-handed neutrinos with zero electroweak interaction likely exist.

Second, chirality is only conserved when it coincides with helicity.  What's really conserved is *angular momentum*.

A left-handed neutrino + a left-handed anti-neutrino cannot annihilate under the standard model.  $\nu_L + \bar\nu_L \to Z^0$ is impossible, as $\bar\nu_L$ is sterile.  In fact $\psi_L + \bar\psi_L\to (?)$ is impossible for any $\psi$ under the SM.  But any annihilations of hypothetical massless Weyl fermions would conserve angular momentum.

Comment: The fact that neutrinos have mass does not imply that right-handed neutrinos exist. This conclusion would only follow if the mass is a Dirac mass, but it could also be a Majorana mass.

Comment: @flippiefanus Edited.  But why not just edit the otherwise helpful answer to a confused question, rather than angrily downvoting?

Comment: The downvoter is not me